# Tomcat trying to get access to file system on Windows Server 2008

Tags: tomcat, windows-server-2008, tomcat7, filenotfoundexception

This time I'm having problem with tomcat7 running as service on Windows 2008 R2. I' going to read some internal file stored under `Web-inf/classes/` folder.

Despite the fact that tomcat is starting from Administrator account I can't read required files. It doesn't meter if I place it directly on C: drive or in classes folder- all the time I'm getting `FileNotFoundException`.

I tried to list all files from the folder, but it seems to be empty, but it's not. I can access there with explorer. Trying to get read properties in java I'm getting 'false'.
I'm struggling with it some time and have no idea what is wrong. Please help :)

Comment: How are you trying to read the file? Give us a bit of code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody having this same problem. It appears that Tomcat doesn't work correctly with path containing white spaces. It was places in 'Program Files folder' and the file it was looking for was places in classes under web-inf folder.
Regards
Jan